# Does Unity pad textures into rectangles?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I already know that if Unity is using a texture with the dimensions 250X250 it will pad the texture to 256X256 so as to make the dimensions a power of 2.  If I were to have a texture of size 512X256 would it pad to 512X512 to make the texture a square or would it stay at 512X256 as each side is already a power of 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should keep the 512x256 resolution. Each side needs to be a power of two, they don't have to be equal.

Note, that it's not exactly true that Unity will change the dimensions of each your texture. You can change the texture properties to legacy GUI and then you can have a pixel perfect texture. It will be wasteful or slower a bit (depending on GPU drivers), but it will work quite well.